# AOF rewrite behavior in redis

Tags: redis

I could see redis AOF rewrite is happening not at the default value of 100% growth every time. Some time the growth is too high before rewrite is happening. Is there any load condition that preventing redis to start the compaction at 100% growth every time ?

" Starting automatic rewriting of AOF on 24886% growth"

The first AOF rewrite happened at 100% growth, but the next rewrite happened at 24886% growth.